# Axios response not shown

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

The following is my code:

```
async function asynccall() {
  //POST request (create order)
  var data = JSON.stringify({
    merchant_urls: {
      terms: "https://www.example.com/terms.html",
      checkout: "https://atelierdecosmetique.herokuapp.com/checkout",
      confirmation: "https://atelierdecosmetique.herokuapp.com/confirmation",
      push: "https://www.example.com/api/push",
    },
  });
  var config = {
    method: "post",
    url: "https://api.playground.klarna.com/checkout/v3/orders/",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: "",
    },
    data: data,
  };


  var orderid = Postrequest.data.order_id;
  //GET Request (read order)
  var axios = require("axios");
  var data1 = JSON.stringify({

    merchant_urls: {
      confirmation: "https://www.example.com/confirmation.html" + Postrequest.data.order_id,
    },
  });
  var config1 = {
    method: "get",
    url: "https://api.playground.klarna.com/checkout/v3/orders/",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization:
    },
    data: data1,
  };

  //The calls as variables
  var Postrequest = await axios(config);
  var Getrequest = await axios(config1);

  console.log(Getrequest.data.merchant_urls.confirmation)

  app.get("/checkout", function(req, res) {
    res.render("checkout.ejs", {
      datapost: Postrequest.data.html_snippet
    })
  });

  app.get("/confirmation", function(req, res) {
    res.render("confirmation.ejs", {
      dataget: Getrequest.data.html_snippet
    });
  });
}
asynccall();
```

My problem with this code is that the `Postrequest.data.order_id` is not shown in the GET request's `merchant_urls.confirmation` URL when I console log it at the end of the code. It should return the confirmation page URL with the order_id response from the POST request at the end. How could I solve this? I know it has to do with asynchronous and synchronous code? I'm stuck and really need this to work.

Comment: The code looks fine, I don't think there's a problem with asynchrony. You're not getting any errors, are you? I'd rather assume that you are simply using the klarna API in the wrong manner, and the response does contain an error code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the results of the first request before using the returned data in the second.

```js
async function asynccall() {
  var axios = require("axios");

  //POST request (create order)
  var data = JSON.stringify({
    merchant_urls: {
      terms: "https://www.example.com/terms.html",
      checkout: "https://atelierdecosmetique.herokuapp.com/checkout",
      confirmation: "https://atelierdecosmetique.herokuapp.com/confirmation",
      push: "https://www.example.com/api/push",
    },
  });

  var config = {
    method: "post",
    url: "https://api.playground.klarna.com/checkout/v3/orders/",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: "",
    },
    data: data,
  };
  
  var Postrequest = await axios(config);
  var orderid = Postrequest.data.order_id;

  //GET Request (read order)
  var data1 = JSON.stringify({
    merchant_urls: {
      confirmation: "https://www.example.com/confirmation.html" + Postrequest.data.order_id,
    },
  });
  var config1 = {
    method: "get",
    url: "https://api.playground.klarna.com/checkout/v3/orders/",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: ""
    },
    data: data1,
  };

  //The calls as variables
  var Getrequest = await axios(config1);

  console.log(Getrequest.data.merchant_urls.confirmation)

  app.get("/checkout", function(req, res) {
    res.render("checkout.ejs", {
      datapost: Postrequest.data.html_snippet
    })
  });

  app.get("/confirmation", function(req, res) {
    res.render("confirmation.ejs", {
      dataget: Getrequest.data.html_snippet
    });
  });
}
asynccall();
```

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: The code in my answer should do that, assuming the authorization props in the requests are filled in.